# powershell and conda: conda activate env returns command not found

Tags: powershell, terminal, conda

I have pip installed `powerline-shell` in my `base` conda env. Switching envs yields the following error:

```
conda activate <env_name>
-bash: powerline-shell: command not found
```

I also tried running `conda init powershell` but it took no actions.

I have miniconda3, with conda 4.7, installed on MacOS Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a simple solution to this. I'm thinking you either need to install it in every env (which I don't recommend because it's best to avoid using `pip` in Conda) or you create a link to the `powerline-shell` binary in another location that you can keep on `PATH` to avoid adding the entire `miniconda3/bin/` directory to `PATH`. I've done something like this in the past, but never with a Python entry point before.

I'd try something like

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
ln -s /your/path/to/miniconda3/bin/powerline-shell ~/.local/bin/powerline-shell
```

Then add `.local/bin` to `PATH` in your `.bashrc`, probably toward the beginning (e.g., before the Conda section).  The path here (`~/.local/bin`) is totally arbitrary, so adjust to your preferences. Main point is to minimize what you are exposing globally in a shell session.

Note: `conda init powershell` is for Windows PowerShell users.